# Can't change activity in my App using PlainText as login

Tags: android-studio

I am a noob developer in android who is just learning to experiment with activities and stuff like that. Today I learnt about TextFields, and tried to use a normal plaintext EditText view as a username, a password-input type EditText view, and a button to which an onClick method by the name of "loginMethod" was attached. I used simple if-else statements by taking the inputs in the text fields to string and want to open a new activity when the desired username and password are entered, and to show a toast if not. However, on running the application it only gives the toast message for the error and doesn't start the activity.

The code for the method is attached below:

```
public void loginMethod(View view)
    {
        EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        String user_name=username.getText().toString();
        String pass_word=password.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Info","Entered username: "+user_name+" and Entered password: "+pass_word);
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        int duration= Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        if (user_name=="myuser" && pass_word == "mypass")
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,welcome.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Username or Password!",duration).show();
    }
```

The output when the image is run is also attached in the image below. Please help.
[Check out the output screenshot from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SboLj.png)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/string-equals-versus
You cannot compare strings in Java with ```==``` operator

Comment: Thanks @Teempy, used ```user_name.equals(myuser)``` and that worked.

Comment: See my answer and my comments under it please

Comment: You can check my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if (user_name.text.toString()=="myuser" && pass_word.text.toString() == "mypass")
```

Comment: Thanks, but as the user above mentioned, we can't compare strings using ```==``` in Java.
I used ```user_name.equals(myuser)``` and that worked.
Nevertheless, thanks! <3

Comment: if my code works correctly, you can check it as correct answer.@SanskarUpadhyay

Comment: Try this simple code to see we can compare two strings with == operator @Sanskar

Comment: public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String a="abcd";
         String b="abcd";
         if(a==b)
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}@Sanskar